# Using OVER and ORDER BY clause in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 (MSSRB) to build a Pareto chart for NCRs (Non-Conformance Reports) by vendor.  Basically I want to see how many NCRs are submitted for each vendor.  I have no trouble pulling the data in to create a descending bar chart, but the tricky part is creating the cumulative percentage line graph that sits on top of the bar chart.  Since I do not have access to our SQL server yet, I have to do a pre-query in MSSRB to an Excel file, which is a static clone of the SQL data fields.  This is my current query:

```
select  [Vendor],
        [NCRperVendor],
        sum([NCRperVendor]) over (order by [NCRperVendor] desc) as [TotalNCR]
            from (
                select  [Vendor],
                        sum([NCR Counter]) as [NCRperVendor]
                from    [Sheet1$]
                group   by [Vendor]
            ) sub
group   by [Vendor], [NCRperVendor]
order   by [NCRperVendor] desc
```

The subquery retrieves adds up the number of NCRs for each vendor and stores it as NCRperVendor.  Then the outer query uses that information to sort the data, since I want to see the vendor with the most NCRs first.  The sum function in the outer query should create a running total of the NCRs.  However, this is the error I get from MSSRB when I try and run the program:

**"Could not update a list of fields for the query.  Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct.  ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'row_number() over (order by [NCRperVendor] desc)'."**

At first I thought MSSRB doesn't support SQL window functions, but they are being used in this example, which is one of the many examples I am working with: http://www.advancedssrs.com/2014/08/how-can-i-build-pareto-charts-in-ssrs.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The OVER CLAUSE and ROW_NUMBER() windowing function were added to 2012. Many instances are still running 2008/2005.

Comment: Interesting...when I pull up the About page for my install of MSSRB, it says SQL Server 2012 at the top, but the version number is 11.0.2100.60.  Apparently this was released in March 2011.

Comment: Then these functions are available to you. I was just pointing out when support for those was added.

Comment: Thanks Ross, that does clarify my initial thought that they might not be supported.  Which leaves the question, what is the problem with my syntax?

Comment: Because you are querying a spreadsheet, rather than a SQL Server instance you are using the ODBC Excel Driver, which runs ODBC SQL and this does not support all the same functionality as Transact SQL  (i.e. not window functions). If you were connecting to a SQL Server 2012+ database rather than an excel file, your query would be fine.

Comment: I agree wtih GarethD, but I wanted to clear up a statement by @RossBush, ROW_NUMBER was adding starting with SQL 2008 not 2012. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx as where other ranking and aggregate functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx.  Analytic functions such as LAG, LEAD, PERCENTILE_COUNT where introduced in 2012

Comment: @Matt - Thanks, you are correct a few were added in 2008 and more in 2012. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Matt, I don't really want to be *that* guy, especially after you have agreed with me, but `ROW_NUMBER` was added in 2005.

Comment: @GarethD thanks! I thought so, but I couldn't find 2005 in the documentation and I don't have 2005 around anymore so I couldn't try it.